# Insertion sort in VBA - not working

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting, vba

I have a loop that creates a random list of rational numbers, I'm trying to create a macro that will organise the numbers descending using an insertion sort algorithm.

Creates a random list of rational numbers:

```
Sub SetUpList12()
    Dim UnsortedList(1 To 100, 1 To 1) As Double
    Dim L As Long
    For L = 1 To 100
        UnsortedList(L, 1) = Rnd(-L)
    Next L
    Range("A1:A10").Value = UnsortedList

End Sub
```

The sorting algorithm: (Not working)

```
Sub InsertSortTest2()

    Dim Num  As Integer
    Dim C  As Integer
    Dim D  As Integer
    Dim Temp  As Integer
    Dim p As Integer

    p = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Cells(2, 5) = p 'Just to check'

    ReDim Arr(p) As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim R As Long

    For R = 1 To p
        i = Cells(R, 1)
        Num = p
        For C = 0 To Num - 1
            Arr(C) = i
        Next C
        For C = 1 To Num - 1
            D = C
            While D > 0 And (Arr(D) < Arr(D - 1))
                Temp = Arr(D)
                Arr(D) = Arr(D - 1)
                Arr(D - 1) = Temp
                D = D - 1
            Wend
        Next C
        For C = 0 To Num - 1
            Range("A" & C + 1).Value = Arr(C)

        Next C
    Next R
End Sub
```

My insertion sort code is not working - can anyone suggestion a solution?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your question ?? Is your code working or not ??

Comment: Yes, the sorting algorithm is not working.

Comment: Read here how to sort an array (Bubble-Sort) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/830b42cf-8c97-4aaf-b34b-d860773281f7/sorting-an-array-in-vba-without-excel-function?forum=isvvba

Comment: I can't use Bubble sort. has to be insertion sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pretty good implementation of an insertion sort by [Richard Newcombe](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c14627/Sorting-Algorithms-In-VB.htm#page-3) in VB.NET which can be easily re-coded in 16 lines of Excel VBA:

```
Sub InsertionSort(ByRef varData As Variant)

    Dim lngCounter1 As Long
    Dim lngCounter2 As Long
    Dim varTemp As Variant

    For lngCounter1 = 1 To UBound(varData)
        varTemp = varData(lngCounter1)
        For lngCounter2 = lngCounter1 To 1 Step -1
            If varData(lngCounter2 - 1) > varTemp Then
                varData(lngCounter2) = varData(lngCounter2 - 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngCounter2
        varData(lngCounter2) = varTemp
    Next lngCounter1

End Sub
```

Which takes an array and does the insertion sort. The `Sub` takes the array `ByRef` meaning that the array you pass to the function actually gets sorted and there's no 'before' and 'after' array.

The following test code shows it working for `Double`, and `String`. In these examples the array `varData` is a one-dimensional array and therefore to get it to render in a column you need to use the `Transpose` function:

```
ws.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(varData), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)
```

You can update the code to work with the 2-dimensional array by just using `,1` per your original example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoTests()

    Dim lngItemsToSort As Long
    Dim varData As Variant
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ''' double
    ' create 0-base array for test data
    lngItemsToSort = 9 ' 10-element array
    ReDim varData(0 To lngItemsToSort)

    ' get reference to a sheet and clear
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.ClearContents

    ' create test data for Double
    VBA.Randomize
    For lngCounter = LBound(varData) To UBound(varData)
        varData(lngCounter) = VBA.Rnd
    Next lngCounter

    ' show test data
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varData), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

    ' sort test data
    InsertionSort varData

    ' output sorted test data
    ws.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(varData), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

    MsgBox "Sorted Double values"

    ''' string
    ' create 0-base array for test data
    lngItemsToSort = 9 ' 10-element array
    ReDim varData(0 To lngItemsToSort)

    ' get reference to a sheet and clear
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.ClearContents

    ' create test data for Double
    VBA.Randomize
    For lngCounter = LBound(varData) To UBound(varData)
        varData(lngCounter) = Chr(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(65, 122))
    Next lngCounter

    ' show test data
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(varData), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

    ' sort test data
    InsertionSort varData

    ' output sorted test data
    ws.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(varData), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varData)

    MsgBox "Sorted String values"

End Sub

Sub InsertionSort(ByRef varData As Variant)

    Dim lngCounter1 As Long
    Dim lngCounter2 As Long
    Dim varTemp As Variant

    For lngCounter1 = 1 To UBound(varData)
        varTemp = varData(lngCounter1)
        For lngCounter2 = lngCounter1 To 1 Step -1
            If varData(lngCounter2 - 1) > varTemp Then
                varData(lngCounter2) = varData(lngCounter2 - 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngCounter2
        varData(lngCounter2) = varTemp
    Next lngCounter1

End Sub
```

### Edit

The following code will work with the OPs 2d array:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetUpList12()
    Dim UnsortedList(0 To 99, 1 To 1) As Double
    Dim L As Long
    For L = 0 To 99
        UnsortedList(L, 1) = Rnd(-L)
    Next L
    Range("A1:A100").Value = UnsortedList

    'sort the list
    InsertionSort UnsortedList

    Range("B1:B100").Value = UnsortedList

End Sub

Sub InsertionSort2DArrayForRange(ByRef varData As Variant)

    Dim lngCounter1 As Long
    Dim lngCounter2 As Long
    Dim varTemp As Variant

    For lngCounter1 = 1 To UBound(varData, 1)
        varTemp = varData(lngCounter1, 1)
        For lngCounter2 = lngCounter1 To 1 Step -1
            If varData(lngCounter2 - 1, 1) > varTemp Then
                varData(lngCounter2, 1) = varData(lngCounter2 - 1, 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next lngCounter2
        varData(lngCounter2, 1) = varTemp
    Next lngCounter1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer. However, this doesn't seem to work. maybe I'm implementing it incorrectly, but i've tried 50+ times in many different ways to integrate it into my code above and it refuses to work.

Comment: I added code that will work with your array but had to change first dimension to be 0-based - e.g. `Dim UnsortedList(0 To 99, 1 To 1) As Double` instead of `Dim UnsortedList(1 To 100, 1 To 1) As Double`

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie, why is the 1 To 1 dimension required?